# Child Process will neither complete nor abort in Windows?

Tags: java, ffmpeg, runtime.exec

How to make my java parent process wait till child process gets completed. I have tried with `runtime.exec` and with `processBuilder.pb`:

```
String cmd = "ffmpeg -i input.vob output.mp4" 
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec(cmd); 
proc.waitFor();
```

---

This works fine with small input file (say less than 10 Mb). If I give larger input file then program will be hanged. Output file will be partially created and file creation will be hanged and control will not return. Even `proc.join(10000);` did not give any useful result. Here parent process is terminating before child process (ffmpeg) gets completed.

How to overcome this problem?

Comment: Read and implement *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html).  Then ignore it refers to `exec(..)` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to build the `Process`.  Also break a `String args` into `String[] args` to account for arguments that contain spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the data outputted by the process.

A process has 2 output streams: standard output and error output. You have to read both because the process might write to both of those outputs.

The output streams of the process have buffers. If the buffer of an output stream is filled, attempt to write further data to that by the process is blocked.

Do something like this:

```
InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();  // To read process standard output
InputStream err = proc.getErrorStream(); // To read process error output

while (proc.isAlive()) {
    while (in.available() > 0)
        in.read(); // You might wanna echo it to your console to see progress

    while (err.available() > 0)
        err.read(); // You might wanna echo it to your console to see progress

    Thread.sleep(1);
}
```